# systemd timer every X hours on a specific day

Tags: systemd-timer

I want a timer for a specific day (every year specific month and day) repeating every 8 hours on that day (birthday reminder).
I have tested several including:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tom Birthday
Requires=Tom_Birthday.service

[Timer]
Unit=Tom_Birthday.service
OnCalendar=*-10-2 00/8:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

No one works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your computer is presumably not running in 1998, you can’t use that; if you don’t specify the year, it works:

```
$ systemd-analyze calendar "10-2 0/8:00"
  Original form: 10-2 0/8:00                 
Normalized form: *-10-02 00/8:00:00          
    Next elapse: Sat 2021-10-02 00:00:00 CEST
       (in UTC): Fri 2021-10-01 22:00:00 UTC 
       From now: 8 months 18 days left
```

(using my local time).

Comment: I use it to `notify-send` and it triggers upon adding systemd timer